# Strange jQueryUI dialog error

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog

I have dialog created like this

```
$('#add_error').click(function(e) {
        $('<div>')
            .load('/someaction/format/html/')
            .dialog({
                title: 'Some title',
                modal: true,
                width: 385,
                close: function() {
                     $(this).remove();
                }
            });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

It works ok, but every third (not really sure if its really third) time I click link to open dialog, it fails with error in firebug

"$("").addClass("ui-widget-overlay") is undefined"

In dialog.js that is piece of code:

```
var $el = (this.oldInstances.length ? this.oldInstances.splice(0, 1)[0] : $('<div></div>').addClass('ui-widget-overlay'))
                .appendTo(document.body)
                .css({
                    width: this.width(),
                    height: this.height()
                });
```

under create: function(dialog) method.

Strange thing is that this error does not occur when I remove

```
close: function() {
                     $(this).remove();
                }
```

Any idea?

Comment: Which versions of JQuery / JQuery UI are you running ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in trunk since 1.8rc3. See http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/5263

Answer (score 0):

I think it got to be connected to the: ui-widget-overlay in some strange way.

I just override it in my page like this:
    
    .ui-dialog-titlebar { display: none; }
    .ui-widget-overlay { background: #888888; opacity:.15;filter:Alpha(Opacity=15); }

and the reason to override ui-widget-overlay is just because
the following doesn't work
    .ui-dialog-overlay { background: #888888; opacity:.15;filter:Alpha(Opacity=15); }

Answer (score 0):

Everithing works with jQuery UI 1.8